# Downloading file from database with ajax (File is corrupted or cannot be opened)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am saving a file to the database with the codes below.

controller.cs,

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddFile(IFormFile file, TaskListAttachment taskListAttachment)
        {
            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.Combine("wwwroot/files", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                taskListAttachment.FileName = file.FileName;
                taskListAttachment.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                taskListAttachment.Data = new byte[file.Length];
                taskListAttachment.AddDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                taskListAttachment.FilePath = fileName;
                taskListAttachment.TaskId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.Where(x => x.Key == "TaskId").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                taskListAttachment.AddUserId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.Where(x => x.Key == "AddUserId").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                taskListAttachmentManager.itemAdd(taskListAttachment);
                var addValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskListAttachment);
                return Json(addValue);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(null);
            }
        }
```

cshtml,

```
<script>
        $("#fileInput").change(function () {
            var fileName = $(this).val();
            var fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            $("#fileExtension").val(fileExtension);
        });

        $("#uploadButton").click(function () {
            var addUserId = $("#addUserId").data("user-id");
            var taskId = $("#taskId").data("task-id");
            var fileExtension = $("#fileExtension").val();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("AddUserId", addUserId);
            formData.append("TaskId", taskId);
            formData.append("FileExtension", fileExtension);
            formData.append("file", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/TaskList/AddFile/",
                type: "Post",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    var dismissModal = document.getElementById("dismissButton").click();
                    attachmentalert();
                    var FileInput = $('#fileInput');
                    FileInput.val('').focus();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I then wrote the following codes to download the saved file,

controller.cs,

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
        {
            var attachment = taskListAttachmentManager.itemGetById(id);
            if (attachment != null)
            {
                return File(attachment.Data, attachment.ContentType, attachment.FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

cshtml,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "TaskList", new {id = item.AttachmentID})" class="text-dark fs-4 link lh-sm">@item.FileName</a>
```

But when I download files, they download incorrectly or corrupted. If I download jpeg or png, the image won't open, if I download rar or zip, I get a warning that the archive is corrupt or incorrect. The same goes for office files and pdf.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I checked it on a txt file and when I downloaded it, it came up empty.

Comment: The site cannot be reached, is the address correct?

Comment: I noticed that you shared the code snippets both for uploading and downloading, could you pls help confirm if the files uploaded by your code is good to open directly? I mean, could you pls open  the png/jpeg/zip/txt file stored in `wwwroot/files` directly? If yes, then the issue might relate to the download, if not, the issue might relate to the upload.

Comment: this doesn't look right:  taskListAttachment.Data = new byte[file.Length];  Seems like that should be set to the stream.  (you may want stream.Position = 0; first, btw...)   If this is untrusted user input, you should be aware that the code, as is, is vulnerable to attack.